# Socket IO cross sub-domain handshake fails

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, apache2

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

I have 2 sub-domains pointing at the same server, one is for a react application the other is for the API which provides a socket IO connection

I keep getting this error above in my browser console

I noticed these errors in my apache logs:

```
AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /socket.io/
AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 0.0.0.0:3040
```

Here is my `apache` config, I am using `ProxyPass`:

```sh
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3040/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3040/
```

In my front-end I connect using `socket.io-client`:

```js
let socket = io(process.env.GATSBY_CHATBOT_SOCKET_URL, {transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']});
```

My `nodejs` server using `socket.io`:

```js
const https = require('https');

let options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.PRIV_KEY_PATH),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH),
    passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE,
};

let server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
    console.log('listening on https port: ' + process.env.PORT);
});

let ioOptions = {
    pingInterval: 10000,
    pingTimeout: 60000,
    origins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local' ? null : '*.mydomain.com',
    transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling'],
};

let io = new require('socket.io')(server, ioOptions);
```

What am I missing here? Why can't I get my websocket handshake to work?

Comment: did you set up your `apache`  to upgrade the connection?

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair What do you mean by upgrade the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem and it is actually very simple

1. **Make sure you have SSLProxyEngine on**

   - Add `SSLProxyEngine on` before `ProxyPass` line
2. **Make sure you set the headers**

   - Add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://YOURDONAIN.com"`

That sorted me out, I hope this is helpful to others.